# Getting a Google API Account

Tags: api, seo

What URL can I visit to get myself a Google API Account?  While sites point to http://www.google.com/apis and talk of "easy steps", I just can't figure it out.

#### Background:

There are places on the web that offer google services if you give them your Google API account key (in my case http://www.freesitemapgenerator.com and index retrieval).

They say to go to http://www.google.com/apis, but that just redirects me to http://code.google.com.  There are no "easy instructions" for me to follow to get an account.

Am I going crazy here?  (I have analytics and webmaster tools etc activated, so I somewhat know what I'm doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create project, as API key is associated with project. Here you can do this 
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Answer (score 6):

[Since December 2006, Google is no longer issuing these API keys](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you apply for an API *key*, and you can do that with any Google account.  The various API's appear to require different keys.  To get a key for the Maps API, visit:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

The [products directory](http://code.google.com/more/) on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/) lists each of the products for which Google appears to offer some sort of interaction from developers, some of which have API keys.  Take a look at that page and visit the home page for each product in order to obtain a key.

Specifically, you can look at the [Google AJAX API's](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/) page, which features each of the products for which an AJAX API exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/signup.html) and remember that "A single Maps API key is valid for a single "directory" or domain".